# Python Sleep Until a Certain Time

Tags: python, thread-safety, scheduled-tasks, sleep

I have a Python script and I want too run it at 3 am. Would like to simply put something like this at the top of it.

```
while not 3am:
    sleep(10)
```

That way it keeps sleeping for 10 seconds until it's 3am. At 3am, it executes the rest of the code below this and then exits the script.  Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: No, this would not be correct. You would want to use a ready-to-use service provided by your OS. Either crontab on a *nix environment or Windows Scheduler on a Windows environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution with a sleep-wait loop:

```
import datetime
import time

target_time = datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 7, 3)  # 3 am on 3 July 2017
while datetime.datetime.now() < target_time:
    time.sleep(10)
print('It is 3am, now running the rest of the code')
```

If instead of sleeping, you want to do other work, consider using [threading.Timer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects) or the [*sched* module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html#sched.scheduler).

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I want but I think there is minor error.  Shouldn't it be:  datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 3, 3) to go at 3 am tomorrow morning?

Comment: @Matt Put in any date and time you want :-)